# Android Studio - How to Customize Logcat Output Format ?

Tags: android, format, android-studio, android-logcat

I want to know which way to change `Logcat Output Format` in Android DDMS.
I 'm using Android Studio 0.4.2 on MAC. I know that I can customize the format from terminal but I also need to do this in Android DDMS Monitor tool.

[Link to customize .](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#DebuggingWebPages)

Comment: vote for this feature request here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69879